# Primefaces, activeindex actionlistener not calling in multiple tabs

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Hello i am using primefaces version 3.2
The ui layout which i am using is
tabview, inside it, i've accordion panel, and inside every tab of the accordion, i've two forms.

Just like

tabview>tab>accordionpanel>tab>form1 and

tabview>tab>accordionpanel>tab>form2 and so on...

Now, the problem is that the active index action is not called in the above scenario. However, when i remove on of the froms from the accordion panel tab, it is called and works fine.

This is my xhtml tabview code

```
        <p:tabView id="tabView" activeIndex="#{profileInfoManagedBean.myCurrentTab}" >
            <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{profileInfoManagedBean.tabIsChanged}" />

            <p:tab id="locationInfoTab" title="Location Info">

                <p:accordionPanel id="aPanel">

                    <p:tab id="tab1" title="Country">
                        <h:form id="form1">
                            <p:growl id="growl" life="5000" />

                            <p:messages id="messages"  /> 

                            <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">

                                <p:column>
                                    <h:outputLabel for="country"  value="Country: "></h:outputLabel>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>
                                    <p:inputText id="country" value="#{profileInfoManagedBean.country.country}" required="true" label="City">

                                        <f:validateLength minimum="5" maximum="20" />
                                        <p:ajax event="blur" update="msg1"></p:ajax>
                                    </p:inputText>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>
                                    <p:message id="msg1" for="country" display="icon"></p:message>
                                </p:column>

                            </h:panelGrid>
                            <p:commandButton type="submit" action="#{profileInfoManagedBean.addCountry}" value="Save" ajax="true" ></p:commandButton>

                        </h:form>
                        <p:separator />

                        <h:form id="countryDataTableForm">
                            <p:panel>
                                <p:growl id="messagesww" />
                                <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog" message="Are you sure you want to delete the selected row ?"
                                                 header="Deleting Row" severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation1">
                                    <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Yes Sure" update="messagesww" oncomplete="confirmation1.hide()"
                                                     action="#{profileInfoManagedBean.deleteObject}" />
                                    <p:commandButton id="decline" value="Not Yet" onclick="confirmation1.hide()" type="button" />
                                </p:confirmDialog>

                                <p:dataTable style="width: 700px;" var="coun" value="#{profileInfoManagedBean.countryList}" selection="#{profileInfoManagedBean.deletingObj}" rowKey="#{coun.countryId}"
                                             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                                             paginator="true" rows="5" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,15,20,25" editable="true">
                                    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" update="@this"
                                            listener="#{profileInfoManagedBean.onEditRow}" />


                                    <p:column headerText="Country">
                                        <p:cellEditor>
                                            <f:facet name="output">
                                                <h:outputText value="#{coun.country}" />
                                            </f:facet>
                                            <f:facet name="input">
                                                <p:inputText value="#{coun.country}" style="width:100%" />
                                            </f:facet>
                                        </p:cellEditor>
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column id="inactive" filterBy="#{coun.isActive}"   
                                              headerText="isActive" footerText="exact" 
                                              filterOptions="#{profileInfoManagedBean.isActiveDropDown}"
                                              filterMatchMode="exact">

                                        <p:cellEditor>
                                            <f:facet name="output">
                                                <h:outputText value="#{coun.isActive}"></h:outputText>
                                            </f:facet>
                                            <f:facet name="input">
                                                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{coun.isActive}" >  
                                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="True" itemValue="true" />  
                                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="False" itemValue="false" /> 
                                                </h:selectOneMenu> 
                                            </f:facet>
                                        </p:cellEditor>
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column headerText="Edit">
                                        <p:rowEditor />
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column headerText="Delete">

                                        <p:commandButton type="button" onclick="confirmation1.show()" 
                                                         id="delCountry" title="Delete Country" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" />
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column selectionMode="single">
                                        <f:facet name="header">
                                            <h:outputText value="select" />
                                        </f:facet>
                                    </p:column>


                                </p:dataTable>
                            </p:panel>

                        </h:form>
                    </p:tab>

                </p:accordionPanel>

            </p:tab>

            <p:tab id="basicInfoTab" title="Basic Info">
                <p:accordionPanel id="aPanel2">
                    <p:tab id="tab2" title="basic   info">
                        <h:form id="dkk">
                            This is basic info tab.
                        </h:form>
                        <h:form id="ddkk">
                            This is basic info tab.
                        </h:form>
                    </p:tab>
                </p:accordionPanel>
            </p:tab>

        </p:tabView>   




 I've got multiple tabs in the tabview and also multiple tabs in each accordion panel.

    Waiting for the response.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
<p:tab  id="tab1" title="Quick Search"> 
<p:commandButton   process="tab1"  value="Search"  
 actionListener="#{TTCPage.searchTrackTime}"  id="searchval" update="track"/>
```

Comment: I am using active index here that whenever a tab is clicked, it's stored in the bound bean member variable. 
In your suggestion, i've to press the command button to do it and not the tab.

Please explain if you didn't want to say what i got from ur code.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is your bean in view scoped? if you put a breakpoint in the getter of myCurrentTab, does it stop in debug mode?

Comment: My bean is session scoped. 
and in the debug mode, when i step over at the "return myCurrrentTab" statement, it goes to the return statement of the invoke method of Method.java class. But it doesn't stop the debugger.

Comment: do you really need the accordionPanel panel?, I always had problems with complex components inside tabs. Maybe you can ask at primefaces. Or you could use another component.